# Getting error while binding view with a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Every property is present in the model. But still getting error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_vzy5d524.dll but was not handled in user code
```

I am not getting why this error is occuring. Things were working fine not started getting error.

Please guide if any idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Some where you are trying to access a property/calling a method on a NULL object !

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that your model value is NULL